# How can I increase the max num of concurrent jobs in Dataproc?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I need to run hundreds of concurrent jobs in a Dataproc cluster, each job is pretty lightweight (e.g., a Hive query which gets a table metadata) which doesn't take much resources.  But there seem to be some unknown factors which limit the max concurrent jobs. What can I do if I want to increase the max concurrency limit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the jobs through the Dataproc API / CLI, these are the factors which affect the max number of concurrent jobs:

1. The number of master nodes;
2. The master memory size;
3. The cluster properties `dataproc:agent.process.threads.job.max` and `dataproc:dataproc.scheduler.driver-size-mb`, see [Dataproc Properties](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties#dataproc_service_properties_table) for more details.

For debugging, when submitting jobs with gcloud, SSH into the master node and run `ps aux | grep dataproc-launcher.py | wc -l` every a few seconds to show how many concurrent jobs are running. At the same time, you can run `tail -f /var/log/google-dataproc-agent.0.log` to monitor how the agent is launching the jobs. You can tune the parameters above to get a higher concurrency.

You can also try submitting the jobs directly from the master node through spark-submit or Hive beeline, which will bypass the Dataproc job concurrency control mechanism. This can help you identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: does the  dataproc.scheduler.max-concurrent-jobs cluster properties also affect the max number of concurrent jobs?

Comment: Yes, it does, see the doc.